# Python list is not being appended to if value found in another list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have some code that is supposed to parse some sql statements. 
For some reason the `cmd_ordered_list` only seems to contain 'update' rather than all the other statements. It seems to me this line is not working as it should:
`if(cmd in def_ordered_list):`. Am I missing something obvious here?

```
sql_statements = {} 
sql_select = {'select': 'select, *, from, where, and'}
sql_delete = {'delete': 'delete, from, where, and'}
sql_update = {'update': 'update, index, set, where, and'}
sql_insert = {'insert': 'insert, into, source'}

sql_statements.update(sql_select)
sql_statements.update(sql_delete)
sql_statements.update(sql_update)
sql_statements.update(sql_insert)

cmd = "update index employees set col = 'Hello'"
cmd_list = cmd.split()
first_cmd = cmd_list[0] # update
def_ordered_list = sql_statements[first_cmd].split(",")
cmd_ordered_list = []

for cmd in cmd_list:
    if(cmd in def_ordered_list):
        cmd_ordered_list.append(cmd)

print def_ordered_list
print cmd_ordered_list # only contains 'update' ?? why?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input contains spaces:

```
>>> 'update, index, set, where, and'.split(',')
['update', ' index', ' set', ' where', ' and']
```

Note the spaces before `index`, `set`, `where` and `and`. You never account for those spaces when doing list membership; you should probably strip those first. Or better yet, not store those options as a string in the first place.

If you stored *sets* in your `sql_statements` mapping you avoid issues with splitting, and as an extra bonus make membership testing way faster than when using lists:

```
sql_statements = {
    'select': {'select', '*', 'from', 'where', 'and'},
    'delete': {'delete', 'from', 'where', 'and'},
    'update': {'update', 'index', 'set', 'where', 'and'},
    'insert': {'insert', 'into', 'source'},
}
```

Creating the ordered list is then as simple as:

```
cmd = "update index employees set col = 'Hello'"
cmd_list = cmd.split()
cmd_ordered_list = [s for s in cmd_list[] if s in sql_statements[cmd_list[0]]]
```

Comment: Awesome. Can't believe I missed such an obvious thing. Thank you!